# Is it possible to use one intent to detect all user input to be use to query data from Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I am trying to connect my chat bot created using `Dialogflow` to the `Google Cloud Firestore`. I was thinking if I have to map the intent in the fulfillment one by one that'd be a huge amount of work.

Is it possible to write a fulfillment to detect the user input and maps to the intent then go on to query data from the Firestore?

For example, I would like the agent below to map the user input to the intent I already created then query

```java
function intentHandler(agent) {
    const userInput = request.body.queryResult.parameters['Entity_detected'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow provides default intent called `Fallback Intent`. It will be called when there is no matching intent found.

You can take advantage of this and call webhooks on this intent.

Checkout [official document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-default#default_fallback_intent)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed map to a different intent using the user input. For this you can use [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) to map to a different intent after sending a response. I've never tried it with entities, but I imagine it would be implemented something like this.

```
const userInput = request.body.queryResult.parameters['Your Entity'];
switch (typeof(userInput)) {
  case SelectQueryEntity:
    // perform select query
    conv.ask("I've performed a select query");
    conv.context.set("SelectQueryIntent", 1);
    break;

  case UpdateQueryEntity:
    // perform update query
    conv.ask("I've performed a update query");
    conv.context.set("UpdateQueryIntent", 1);
    break;
  etc..
};
```

The context will allow you to navigate the conversation into your desired direction. So if the user inputs anything that matches a SelectQueryEntity, the context will be set to SelectQueryIntent. Any intent which has SelectQueryIntent as an input context will then be allowed to follow up the users next input. Using an intent lifespan of 1 makes this navigation easier to work with.